# Are primary ideals radical ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $Q$ be a primary ideal.
Can we say that $rad$ Q$=$Q?
If $x$ is any element in $Q$, then it is clear that $x$ is in $rad$ Q. 
Does the converse hold?

May you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are primary ideals prime?

Comment: I think that prime ideals (take $n=1$)  are primary but the converse is not true in general.

Comment: And what do you know about the radical of a primary ideal?

Comment: The radical of a primary ideal is prime.

Comment: *Therefore*, the whole point of primary ideals is that they are not radical.

Comment: Try showing that $(9)\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is primary. What is its radical?

Comment: Let $a, b$ be in $Z$ such that $ab$ is in $(9)$ and $a$ is not in $(9)$. Then $ab=9z$ for some $z$ in $Z$ and $3$ divides $a$ or $3$ divides $b$. If $3$ divides $a$, then $a=3z_1$ but $a^k$ is not in $(9)$ for some integer $k$ and hence $b^k$ is in $(9)$. If 3 divides $b$ it is clear that $b^k$ is in $(9)$. So, $(9)$ is primary. I think that its radical $(9)$ is $(3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in general: an ideal $\mathfrak q$ of the noetherian ring $R$ is primary if there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that
$$\operatorname{Ass}R/\mathfrak q =\{\mathfrak p\},$$
and in this case the radical of $\mathfrak q$ is $\mathfrak p$. So unless $\mathfrak q$ is prime…